# Reload tslib touch screen calibration

Tags: qt, touchscreen

**Background:** I am working on a somewhat large Qt-based GUI which handles all user interaction with a touch screen. The program is designed such that the user should not need to access a command prompt in order to do anything, including recalibrating the touch screen. I have written an imitation of tslib's `ts_calibrate` utility which runs as a `QWidget` and can modify tslib's calibration file at `/etc/pointercal`.

However, although I can modify the calibration file, changes to the calibration do not seem to be applied until I close and restart the program. I have written a script which can handle re-opening the program, but I would like to find a more elegant way of doing this so that the user's hassle is kept to a minimum.

**Simply put,** is there a function available in one of Qt's classes which will reload tslib's calibration file on the fly, without restarting the application? I have looked through the [QWSServer class reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwsserver.html) but I did not find anything that looks like it does what I want it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the driver *can* be reloaded without restarting the application. To do so, you can close and re-open the pointer device(s), using methods in the [QWSServer class](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwsserver.html) like so:

```
#include <QWSServer>

...

QWSServer::instance()->closeMouse();
QWSServer::instance()->openMouse();
```

This will cause a reload of tslib's calibration file. E.g., if you started the program with a faulty calibration, correct the calibration file for the touch screen while the program is running, then invoke those methods, the pointer will adjust to the new calibration.

Answer (score 2):

tslib has nothing to do with Qt. You can download the sources of [tslib](https://github.com/kergoth/tslib) and look what tests/ts_calibrate.c does.

Comment: I agree it has nothing to do with Qt by itself, but my version of Qt was compiled with the tslib driver (see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6.2/qt-embedded-pointer.html). As it says there, "The mouse driver is loaded by the server application when it starts running". My question is whether the driver can be reloaded without stopping and restarting the program. I know what ts_calibrate.c does-- in my question, I mentioned that I have reverse-engineered the program already.

Answer (score 0):

[`ts_reconfig()`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/libts0/ts_config.3.en.html) should do what you want.